# Persistent Error in R Markdown to PDF Conversion Despite Multiple Reinstallations

Tags: r, r-markdown

I encountered this issue after installing R. Additionally, I have attempted to resolve it numerous times while using R markdown. However, when attempting to knit it into a PDF file, it fails and displays the same error message.

```
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt) -- "Angel Food Cake"
Copyright (C) 2024 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (<input>:4:36)
[Previously saved workspace restored]
```

I have reinstalled R several times, but it still hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems there is an error in your Rmd file, can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) for more information about asking questions with a reproducible example si others can help you.